# What's the right size of Polarizer and how do I know if it works with my camera?

Tags: polarizer

I've just recently joined the world of photography with a DSLR camera and need some help. I was looking into polarizer filter lens and they come in different sizes, how do I know which one fits my camera? I have a Canon EOS Rebel T5i with a 18-55mm lens. Also how do I know if a Polarizer fits onto the lens of my camera?

Answer (score 0):

Look on the front of your lens. It will probably have some indication of the filter size (possibly 58mm if I've got the right [image](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BW6LWO4)). Look for circular polarizers in 58mm (such as [here](http://www.tiffen.com/displayproduct.html?tablename=filters&itemnum=58CP)). You need a circular polarizer so that your camera's metering system works properly...